# Package errors on every install

Tags: dependencies, macbook, grub-efi

SO I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my mid-2014 Macbook Pro Retina as a standalone partition.

Everything works fine and every applications I installed are working too, but I still get a few errors on every single install or update no matter what.

```
    alex@Alex-LinuxTop:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libass5 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavutil-ffmpeg54
  libbasicusageenvironment0 libbdplus0 libbluray1 libcddb2 libchromaprint0 libcrystalhd3 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.2-9
  libdvbpsi10 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml4v5 libenca0 libfaad2 libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libgme0 libgroupsock1 libgsm1
  libiso9660-8 libkate1 liblivemedia23 libmad0 libmatroska6v5 libmodplug1 libmp3lame0 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4 libopenjpeg5 libopus0
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libproxy-tools libqt5x11extras5 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian
  libshine3 libsidplay2v5 libsoxr0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssh2-1 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtwolame0 libupnp6
  libusageenvironment1 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvdpau1 libvlc5 libvlccore8 libx264-146 libx265-59
  libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xv0 libxvidcore4 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 va-driver-all vdpau-va-driver vlc-data vlc-nox
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
Suggested packages:
  libbluray-bdj libchromaprint-tools python-acoustid firmware-crystalhd libdvdcss2 opus-tools nvidia-vdpau-driver vdpau-driver
  libx265-59-dbg xvba-va-driver videolan-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libass5 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavutil-ffmpeg54
  libbasicusageenvironment0 libbdplus0 libbluray1 libcddb2 libchromaprint0 libcrystalhd3 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.2-9
  libdvbpsi10 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml4v5 libenca0 libfaad2 libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libgme0 libgroupsock1 libgsm1
  libiso9660-8 libkate1 liblivemedia23 libmad0 libmatroska6v5 libmodplug1 libmp3lame0 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4 libopenjpeg5 libopus0
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libproxy-tools libqt5x11extras5 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian
  libshine3 libsidplay2v5 libsoxr0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssh2-1 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtwolame0 libupnp6
  libusageenvironment1 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvdpau1 libvlc5 libvlccore8 libx264-146 libx265-59
  libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xv0 libxvidcore4 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 va-driver-all vdpau-va-driver vlc vlc-data vlc-nox
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
0 upgraded, 76 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 21.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 89.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Get:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe vlc-plugin-notify amd64 2.2.1-3 [5,216 B]                               
Get:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe vlc-plugin-samba amd64 2.2.1-3 [4,910 B]                                
Fetched 21.1 MB in 6s (3,329 kB/s)                                                                                                
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package libbasicusageenvironment0.
(Reading database ... 219118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libbasicusageenvironment0_2014.01.13-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbasicusageenvironment0 (2014.01.13-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcrystalhd3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcrystalhd3_1%3a0.0~git20110715.fdd2f19-11build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpcdec6:amd64 (2:0.1~r459-4.1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpeg2-4:amd64.
[..]
Selecting previously unselected package vlc-plugin-samba.
Preparing to unpack .../vlc-plugin-samba_2.2.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-plugin-samba (2.2.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic (4.2.0-25.30) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: 1: /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: z: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-29ubuntu0.3) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: 1: /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: z: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-29ubuntu0.3); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic depends on linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-genericNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                  is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.2.0.25.27); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic depends on linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic (= 4.2.0-25.30); however:
  Package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.2.0.25.27); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libbasicusageenvironment0 (2014.01.13-1) ...
Setting up libcrystalhd3:amd64 (1:0.0~git20110715.fdd2f19-11build1) ...
Setting up libdirectfb-1.2-9:amd64 (1.2.10.0-5.1) ...
Setting up libdvdread4:amd64 (5.0.0-1ubuntu1) ...
[...]
Setting up vlc-plugin-notify (2.2.1-3) ...
Setting up vlc-plugin-samba (2.2.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.2.1-3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sorry it's a long code but this is when I installed VLC. Thoses packages:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
  linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
     grub-efi-amd64
     grub-efi-amd64-signed
     linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic
     linux-image-generic
     linux-generic
     linux-signed-image-4.2.0-25-generic
     linux-signed-image-generic
     linux-signed-generic
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

They always create thoses same erros.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and it didn't fix it either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: z: not found` - remove or fix this file

Comment: Could you append the contents of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save` to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive, but I think this is your problem:

```
/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: 1: /etc/grub.d/40_custom.save: z: not found
```

It looks to me like your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save` file is damaged, such that it's got a stray `z` character that the system is trying to interpret as a command. I recommend you check this file. Given the filename, I'd expect that to be a backup of an old file, but I'm not entirely sure of that. If I'm right, deleting it might be in order.

Comment: Thanks, deleting the file solved the problem. I still have no idea what that file was about as it was like 0 kb and the content was 'z', but I guess I don't care as long as it worked haha

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` ?

You can try

```
aptitude install linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
```

which should try to repair this broken package and show you more solutions than apt-get ?

I've learned that aptitude will be more efficient to provide solutions to dependencies problem (i.e., it will propose you to downgrade a package if needed) than apt-get, which will be more strict on installing dependencies !

Comment: bain seems to be right, the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom.save` is perhaps problematic !